# i have this database below with field of number of download, how can track and count and store in my database using php

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

**audio table**
1.id
2.artist
3.filename
4.album
5.release
6.audio URL
7.no download
8.no played
9.producer
10.studio,

**video table**
1.id
2.artist
3.filename
4.album
5.release
6.video URL
7.no download
8.no played
9.producer
10.studio

**album table**
1.id
2.album pic
3.title
4.album name
5.release
6.audio URL
7.video URL

Comment: you can help also php code to track and count number of download

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your statement does not explain in which step you are having problems with. The general procedure should be:

1. record with PHP when a download was made (i.e Ajax-Request)
2. connect PHP to the database, there are two ways to do this, either
       use the PHP Database Object (PDO) or MySQL Improved extension
3. verify if the connection to the database is established
4. execute an SQL command in PHP to update the respective row of a table

To help you better, you must explain exactly which of the four steps you have problems with.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a query like this in SQL or MySQL:

```
UPDATE `audio_table`
SET `num_download` = `num_download` + 1
WHERE `id` = 1234
```

If you're only doing it in PHP, then you would lose info on restart or crash (unless you saved it to a file), but the database method is faster.

Comment: how add in php scripts